# Cancel script from popup with Powershell

Tags: powershell, powercli

I am writing some PowerCLI and want a user to cancel a script from a popup that's provided.

```
$path = "$home\Desktop\deploy.csv"
$a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell

If (Test-Path $path ) {
    $b = $a.popup("This file already exists on your Desktop and will be overwritten",0,"PowerCLI Script",1)
    }

} Else {

    echo $null >> $home\Desktop\deploy.csv
}
```

The popup provides a cancel and OK option, what would I need to add for the user to cancel out of the script to not overwrite the existing deploy.csv file?  I found `$MainForm.Close()` but I am unsure how to structure the syntax and if this is the best way to achieve such a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is evaluate the value returned by the popup which is stored in `$b`. If the value is 2 it means the user clicked on Cancel. Then you can simply exit.

```
$path = "$home\Desktop\deploy.csv"
$a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell

If (Test-Path $path ) 
{
    $b = $a.popup("This file already exists on your Desktop and will be overwritten",0,"PowerCLI Script",1)

    if ($b -eq 2)
    {
        exit
    }
} 
Else 
{
    echo $null >> $home\Desktop\deploy.csv
}
```

PS: I fixed a couple of issues with the code as well. Unless this is a portion of larger code, the `Else` statement could not have processed.

Comment: See the [Popup method documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x83z1d9f%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) for full listing of what the possible return values are.

Comment: Thanks Bacon I was looking for that link when you replied :)

Comment: @MickyBalladelli Well, I was in the middle of writing my identical answer and had already found the link when your answer appeared!  :)